# Media controls & download options locked until video hosted in AWS s3 ends

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming

I upload videos to AWS s3 service from an Android app and a Chrome extension and some of them have the option to advance / rewind from the start (The android app ones) while others have to wait until the video ends (The Chrome extension ones)

Both are in the same bucket except one is in a folder while the other is not (below directories)

Example of YES able to advance / rewind & download

https://images-uxmonkey.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2020/1602659309255_video

Home/2020/videogoeshere

Example of NOT able to advance rewind & download

https://images-uxmonkey.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2020/ChromeExtention/screen-capture1599925297.mp4 (1:10 min)

Home/2020/ChromeExtention/videogoeshere

Both are in "content-type: video/mp4" and all the bucket is set to public

THANK YOU!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I can download and play both files just fine using command line tools `wget` and `mpv`. I can also advance and rewind both videos in the same way. However, while the first video plays also in my web browser (Firefox), the second does not. This seems to be an issue with missing web browser video plugin support for your file. Why do you think the problem is caused by AWS? And how is this related to the question title? What do you mean by "video hosted ends"?

Comment: I think the second video file is somehow unusual or problematic, since my desktop video player (`mpv`) struggles to find out the total length of the video. It always thinks only 1 sec is left until video ends at 1 min and 11 sec. Maybe this is related to the web browser not playing the file. So it's really the file causing problems, not AWS.

Comment: @sgrubsmyon by "ends" i mean, finalised / reached the end, you need to wait the whole duration of the video before you can grab the player slider and advance/retrocede it. You also need to wait the whole duration of the video to be able to download it (right click --> save file as).

Its related since the media controls (advance & retrocede) are "locked" (unusable) until the mp4 media file (hosted in AWS s3) ends (reaches its final duration)



I hope i have cleared it and, i think its related to AWS since the other video, hosted in the same place and same file type works properly

Comment: So you think the file is not being properly loaded / saved / created and that is what is causing the issue, makes sense, however, its being correctly branded as "content-type=video/mp4" in AWS and reproduced correctly by the web player

Answer (score 0):

@sgrubsmyon - you were 100% right, the issue was with the file not sending the meta tag of lenght.

This was fixed by activating the "FixVideoSeekingIssues" -->  collab-project/videojs-record#317

Thank you